# How to bypass gin-jwt in the development testing phase

Tags: go, http, jwt

I use [gin-jwt](https://github.com/appleboy/gin-jwt) as authentication in my project, but I want to bypass it during the development phase to test the interface, how can I set up a specific url parameter, such as `debug`, to bypass the authentication and test the interface directly.

Example:
using [jwt-example](https://github.com/appleboy/gin-jwt#example)

- `http://localhost:8000/hello?debug` does not require login
- `http://localhost:8000/hello` requires login

I really appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is to set an environment variable like `MYAPP_CONTEXT=dev`, retrieving that from the environment in your Go code (using `os.Getenv`) and setting up your middleware for JWT authentication to key off that value. So, if the environment variable is set to `dev`, you'd return whatever user/permissions you want. Otherwise, it proceeds as normal.

You could make this also key off the `debug` parameter in the query string if you'd like by checking for it with the gin context's `Query` function so that if and only if the environment is set to `dev` *and* the `debug` parameter is present in the query string do you bypass normal authentication.